# Number test in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, testing, boolean, parseint

I was looking to create a boolean test for a number when it is 10, 20,   30,  40. This would be used  in a loop, 1 to 100. ParseInt seems a bit part but was wondering what a method for a true or false answer maybe.

Answer (score 7):

How about something like:

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
  if (i % 10 == 0) {
    // Something here for multiples of 10
  } else {
    // Something else here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do the following:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
{
  if(i % 10 == 0)
   { 
    //success
   }

}
```

Then you want to use the [modulus operator (%)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm) which returns the remainder of any division. So `x % 10` will be `0` for values of `x` that are multiples of `10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  // Good catch Gert - ! has higher precedence than %, needs parens
  if (!(i % 10)) {
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

Will `alert` i every time i is divisible by 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 etc.

Comment: Fix the typos and this will be the best solution.

  for (var i=1;i<=100;i++) {
    if (!(i % 10)) {
      alert(i);
    }
  }